# Python: Selenium button click doesn't work but '\n' does

Tags: python, selenium, click, phantomjs

Hi I have this short code snippet:

```
    search_box = self.browser.find_elements_by_id('main-search-box')
    search_box[0].click()
    search_box[0].send_keys('{0} {1}'.format(first_name, last_name))
    search_button = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('search-button')
    search_button[0].click()
```

It used to work but today it suddenly stopped working, it is as the button is not clicked. I changed it to:

```
    search_box = self.browser.find_elements_by_id('main-search-box')
    search_box[0].click()
    search_box[0].send_keys('{0} {1}'.format(first_name, last_name))
    search_box[0].send_keys('\n')
```

And now it works fine.
What could be the reason for the original code to not work anymore?

P.S I'm searching on LinkedIn using selenium and PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because in `search_box[0].send_keys('\n')` so `'\n'` string gets recognized as the new line! Usually, to go to the next line we press `ENTER` button =). Basically, `'\n'` is the standard ASCII newline, while KEY_ENTER represents a keyboard code. Enjoy=)

Comment: I understood why the second way worked. I wanted to know why the first one stopped working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try the first version again, cuz I do not see anything bad in there! Also, if can catch something in `console`, add to post!